# Is there a shell one-liner to determine if a block device contains all 0's?

Tags: shell

I would like a command in bash to determine if a Linux block device contains all 0 bytes. I know I could do a hexdump on the device and try to parse the output, but is there something a little more elegant? If this can be done easily in some other scripting language, I'd love to know as well.

Comment: Figuring out some sort of compare to /dev/zero might be a place to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the following to read the first 1MB of the device

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=1024 | sed -e 's/\o00//g' | wc -c
```

For a device with all 0 byte, it'll return 0 as the result.

Answer (score 1):

**All** 0 bytes is impossible, since for many devices it would never terminate (There's no end of `/dev/zero`). You can check the first few bytes (replace /dev/zero with the stream you're testing):

```
count=0
while IFS= read -r -d ''
do
    if [ -z "$REPLY" ]
    then
        let count++
    else
        echo "Found non-NUL character"
        break
    fi
    if [ $count -eq 5 ]
    then
        echo "Found 5 NUL characters at the start of the stream"
        break
    fi
done < /dev/zero
```